# What is the right way to get Azure Cognitive service account endpoint from Azure-CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I was using the following command

```
$cogVisionEndpoint = (az cognitiveservices account show -n $accountName -g $resourceGroupName --query endpoint --output tsv)
```

but I found out that this stopped working when I ran this on another machine with a slightly newer version of Azure-CLI.

The JSON returned by the `az cognitiveservices account show` command is not consistent and looks like it has changed from version to a version.

How can I reliably get this not having to worry about the version of Azure CLI on the machine that I'm running on?

Or is there a completely different way to get the **endpoint** value?

Answer (score 1):

With the newest version you will find `endpoint` in `properties` and since you rely on CLI version installed on the given machine you can simply modify your code to something like this:

```bsh
$cogVisionEndpoint = (az cognitiveservices account show -n $accountName -g $resourceGroupName --query endpoint --output tsv)

if( !$cogVisionEndpoint ) {
 $cogVisionEndpoint = (az cognitiveservices account show -n $accountName -g $resourceGroupName --query "properties.endpoint" --output tsv)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying :) I thought of that but it's not my question. With this approach, I need to keep an eye out for any changes in Azure-CLI in the future. What I want is to script it and forget about it (wishful thinking I guess).

Comment: You know, you are forced to use what you have at hand (or you can try to install specific version). So your best option is to make your code bulletproof. Please accept my reply as an answer if it helps you.